# Saving getline() output to an external array

Tags: c, getline

The external array srclns should keep each read line from a text file. But reading it's content afterwards seems like read lines are empty strings. What am I missing in the code below?

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSRC 20


char *srclns[MAXSRC];   /* source lines */

size_t read_lines(char *path)
{
  FILE *stream;
  ssize_t read;
  char *lnptr;
  size_t n;
  size_t count;
  stream = fopen(path, "r");
  lnptr = NULL;
  n = 0;
  count = 0;
  if (!stream) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open source '%s'\n", path);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while ((read = getline(&lnptr, &n, stream)) != -1) {
    srclns[count++] = lnptr;
  }
  free(lnptr);
  fclose(stream);
  return count;
}


int main()
{

  size_t n = read_lines("foo.txt");
  for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%zu %s\n", i, srclns[i]);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This prints only the line numbers with seemingly empty strings afterwards:

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

Comment: According to the manual you need to reset `lnptr` to `NULL` each time you call `getline` if you want it to allocate new memory: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html. Also you shouldn't `free(lnptr);` until after you print out the lines

Comment: I can't read anything about allocation of new memory in the manual. Can you point to it? As for freeing, I am saving the lnptr in the array, am I not?

Comment: The pointer is not its content, which gets overwritten.

Comment: @Student: *"If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line."*

Comment: ... otherwise it re-uses the same buffer (you only set the pointer to `NULL` once).

Comment: @UnholySheep Are you sure about the free'ing of `lnptr`? The documentation isn't clear on this, but the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) and my own testing with valgrind show that it must be free'd or else there is a memory leak. Note that the free'ing at this place is only for the last, and thus failing, getline call.

Comment: @Yun I think you are right, I missed the part about having to free in case of a read failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what I can see not only does your program not work but it might have memory leaks. This is due to the behavior of [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) which uses dynamic allocation.

Let's take a closer look at what your program does, in particular the `while ((read = getline(&lnptr, &n, stream)) != -1)` loop:

getline will work with `&lnptr` which is of type `char**`.

- **If the pointer is `NULL`** it will allocate enough memory on heap (dynamic) to store the line that is being read.
- **If the pointer is not `NULL`** then  it is expected to point on a buffer of size `n`

  - **If the buffer is big enough** (greater or equal to the line length) it is used to store the string.
  - **If the buffer is too small** then memory is reallocated by `getline` so there is a big enough buffer available. Upon reallocation, `n` is updated to the new buffer size. And in certain cases reallocation will imply that `lnptr` has to be modified and will be. (This might happen if there is not enough consecutive memory free riIght after the current buffer. In that case the memory will be allocated somewhere else on heap. If this is of interest to you I suggest you research is because dynamic memory allocation is a rather complex topic, else just know the pointer might change, that's enough for now).

Now here are the issues with your program (at least this is what I can infer from the information I have. I might be wrong but this seems the most plausible interpretation):

- **On the first iteration of the loop** `lnptr` is `NULL`. Thus getline allocates memory on heap and stores the line, and update `lnptr` to point on the newly allocated buffer.
- **Within the loop** you store the pointer to the allocated buffer in `srclns[0]`
- **On the subsequent iterations** the buffer is overwritten and maybe resized by getline, and you still store the pointer to the same buffer `srclns[count]`.
- **After the loop** you free the buffer and discard the memory every pointer in `srclns` points to.
- **When you print** you most likely read an invalid memory zone (which is the zone pointed by the pointer you just freed) and luckily it seems to start with an termination character (Last line of your file was probably an empty line and nothing actively changed this memory zone after the free...)

How to fix it:
You could explicitly handle dynamic allocation with `malloc` and/or `calloc` but that seem a bit complicated and, as shown before, `getline` can handle it for you. My suggestion is as follow:

1. Set all your elements in `srclns` to `NULL`

   ```c
   for(int i = 0; i < MAXSRC; ++i)
   {
      srclns[i] = NULL;
   }
   ```
2. Then rework the while loop to pass a new element of `srclns` in each  iteration. Each call to `getline` will see an `NULL` pointer, thus allocating memory and updating the cell of `srclns` to point on it. Bonus with this implementation your certain of never going out of bounds of `srclns`:

   ```c
   for(int i = 0; i < MAXSRC; ++i)
   {
       n = 0
       if(getline(&srclns[i], &n, stream) == -1)
       {
           break;  // We get out if we reached OEF
       }
   }
   ```
3. Free all of this allocated memory in main after you accessed it for your    `printf`

   ```c
   for(int i = 0; i < MAXSRC; ++i)
   {
     if(srclns[i] != NULL)
     {
        free(srclns[i]);
     }
   }
   ```
4. Adjust. I did no test on the code so I might have made some mistakes... feel free to correct it. You might also want to adjust the code to match your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The function `getline` will only allocate memory if `lnptr` is `NULL` ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline)). This is the case for the first iteration, but it will need to be reset to `NULL` afterwards:

```
while ((read = getline(&lnptr, &n, stream)) != -1) {
  srclns[count++] = lnptr;
  lnptr = NULL;
}
```

Otherwise, `lnptr` will still point to the memory allocated in the first iteration for all subsequent iterations and `getline` will repeatedly try to write to that location.

Even though it is not the cause of the problem, the allocated memory should be free'd. For example, by adding these lines before `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++)
  free(srclns[i]);
```

Whether or not using `getline` is a good practice is another discussion which you may want to look into. It is not the most portable solution.

Comment: Is there a more portable function or you meant writing a new getline?

Comment: @Student The problem with `getline` is that it's not guaranteed to be available (also see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline). Portable alternatives are `scanf` (if you are careful to avoid buffer overflows), and using `fgets` for reading and `strcpy` to copy the string. Note that this does require you to handle reading lines into a fixed size buffer.

Comment: @Student Another issue with `getline` is that it, at least currently, seems to use a minimum allocation size of 120 ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036074/length-of-line-in-getline-function-c)). Depending on your input, this may waste memory.

Comment: Also not the principal problem but still... don't forget to check  for `count < MAXSRC`.

Comment: @LoïcNiederhauser That would indeed be better in light of defensive programming, but perhaps Student wanted to provide a succinct code snippet or was absolutely sure the input would never be larger in this theoretical example. If you'd check that bound, then ideally there has to be an error message or reallocation too, and the error state of `getline` is better checked as well, with appropriate handling. In any case, I just wanted to provide a straight answer and make the code work. The next point of discussion would be if there's enough of a justification to use non-portable functions.

Comment: @Yun You're right. All you the point you raised are reasonable and it is a good thing you mentioned them. My concern was just that not checking count was the only one which could lead to unsafe memory access which is c can be a pain to debug. But you're also right, it does make the code (a little) heavier and in a very well directed exercise is not necessary.